# Filtrar <td> com PHP

Tags: php, table

Tenho vários `<td>`

```
<td>Conteúdo</td>
<td>Conteúdo</td>
<td>Conteúdo</td>
<td>Conteúdo</td>
<td>Conteúdo</td>
<td>Conteúdo</td>
```

Eu queria dividir esses `<td>`. Por exemplo, gostaria de só exibir o 2, 3, 6. Estou querendo fazer isso porque a tabela que estou puxando é de outro site. Queria saber como da para fazer usando o PHP.

Comment: O que é este `er`?

Comment: Expressão Regular, mas é opcional

Comment: *Tags* que só você sabe o que significa não devem ser usadas. *Tags* servem para classificar conteúdo. Eu já pensei que era `Entidade-Relacionamento`. Pra mim faria mais sentido. E o que é opcional você pode ate colocar na pergunta mas não usar uma *tag*.

Answer (score 4):

Você pode utilizar **[DOMDocument::loadHTML](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php)** para analisar o conteúdo HTML, exemplo:

```
$html = <<<EOF
<table>
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Col 1</th>
<th>Col 2</th>
<th>Col 3</th>
<th>Col 4</th>
<th>Col 5</th>
<th>Col 6</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>Conteudo 1</td>
<td>Conteudo 2</td>
<td>Conteudo 3</td>
<td>Conteudo 4</td>
<td>Conteudo 5</td>
<td>Conteudo 6</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Conteudo 1</td>
<td>Conteudo 2</td>
<td>Conteudo 3</td>
<td>Conteudo 4</td>
<td>Conteudo 5</td>
<td>Conteudo 6</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
EOF;

// criar um novo documento 
$document = new DOMDocument();
// ler o html
$document->loadHTML($html);
// criar seletor xpath
$selector = new DOMXPath($document);
//selecionar conteudo das td's
$results = $selector->query('//td');
// resultado
foreach($results as $node) {
    echo $node->nodeValue . PHP_EOL;
}
```

**[Exemplo: Ideone](http://ideone.com/lTCuno)**

Comment: O Problema é que tem <thead><tbody> até achegar os <td>

Comment: @AlissonAcioli, veja se minha edição resolve o problema

Answer (score 4):

Se eu entendi bem o que você quer fazer, pode utilizar uma expressão regular para capturar as tags `td` que seria assim `/<td>(.*?)<\/td>/`. Tenha em vista que se houverem mais tabelas nesta string a expressão deverá ser alterada.

```
$str =  "<td>Linha 1</td>" .
        "<td>Linha 2</td>" .
        "<td>Linha 3</td>" .
        "<td>Linha 4</td>" .
        "<td>Linha 5</td>" .
        "<td>Linha 6</td>";

preg_match_all("/<td>(.*?)<\/td>/", $str, $result);

// o array $result[0] possui todas as tags td's encontradas, inclundo a tag
// já o array $result[1] possui apenas o conteúdo das tags td's encontradas
$linhas = $result[1];

echo $linhas[1] . "<br />"; // irá exibir Linha 2
echo $linhas[2] . "<br />"; // irá exibir Linha 3
echo $linhas[5] . "<br />"; // irá exibir Linha 6
```

Answer (score 2):

Eu acho que com ER, se é que possível, seria mais complicado ou menos legível.

Mas é fácil, assumindo que esse HTML esteja numa string, e como alternativa à solução do @abfurlan para caso as tags devam ser mantidas, basta quebrá-la, separando pelas novas linhas (e não pelas tags), iterar e comparar com o índice:

```
$str = '<td>Conteúdo #1</td>
<td>Conteúdo #2</td>
<td>Conteúdo #3</td>
<td>Conteúdo #4</td>
<td>Conteúdo #5</td>
<td>Conteúdo #6</td>';

$tds = explode( "\n", $str );

$slice = array();

array_walk(

    $tds,

    function( $entry, $offset ) use( &$slice ) {
        if( in_array( $offset, array( 1, 2, 5 ) ) ) $slice[] = $entry;
    }
);
```

Eu preferi [array_walk()](http://www.php.net/array_walk), mas você pode fazer com um `foreach` simples, também:

```
foreach( $tds as $offset => $entry ) {
    if( in_array( $offset, array( 1, 2, 5 ) ) ) $slice[] = $entry;
}
```

Quanto a ter outros elementos antes e depois, daí a coisa muda um pouco pois você tem de chegar na string que você postou originalmente e não disse que esta estava no meio de mais HTML.

Pra isso você tem duas opções:

- Analisar sintaticamente o HTML, com [DOM](http://php.net/DOM) ou [SimpleXML](http://php.net/SimpleXML) (que é mais fácil)

  ```
  $xml = simplexml_load_string( $str );

  $tds = $xml -> xpath( '//td' );

  $slice = array();

  foreach( $tds as $offset => $entry ) {
      if( in_array( $offset, array( 1, 2, 5 ) ) ) $slice[] = (string) $entry;
  }
  ```

Ao prejuízo de perder as tags.

- Usar uma Expressão Regular para localizar as `<td>`:

  ```
  $tds = preg_split( '/.*(<td>.*?<\/td>).*/', $str, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY | PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE );
  ```

O problema dessa abordagem é que você recebe um pouco de lixo que você precisa limpar para que os *offsets* coincidam:

```
    $tds = array_values( array_filter( array_map( 'trim', $tds ) ) );
```

[array_map()](http://www.php.net/array_map) com vai aplicar [trim()](http://www.php.net/trim) em todos os índices, [array_filter()](http://www.php.net/array_filter) vai remover as entradas vazias e [array_values()](http://www.php.net/array_values) vai reindexar.

E a iteração continua a mesma.

Comment: Porque você percorre todo o array para pegar os valores necessários? Não seria mais simples e até performático, por exemplo, fazer apenas assim `$slice = array($tds[1], $tds[2], $tds[5]);`, ou no caso de haver muitos itens para serem pegos, usar desta forma: `foreach (array(1, 2, 5) as $key) $slice[] = $tds[$key];`

Comment: Sim, sim, seria melhor. Mas a graça do PHP é essa, poder fazer as coisas de muitos jeitos diferentes. Mas lembre-se de verificar se esse **$key** existe em **$tds** antes de usá-lo pra não gerar Notices. Fico feliz com a iniciativa, você pelo visto entendeu a resposta, diferente de muitos que vêm, perguntam, copiam a resposta e somem.

Answer (score 0):

Já que é de outro site tenta com jquery

```js
$("tr td:nth-child(5)").remove()
$("tr td:nth-child(4)").remove()
$("tr td:first").remove()
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>coluna 1</td>
    <td>coluna 2</td>
    <td>coluna 3</td>
    <td>coluna 4</td>
    <td>coluna 5</td>
    <td>coluna 6</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```